# How do I set up the project in the Android site's "Managing the Activity Lifecycle" training exercise?

Tags: android, lifecycle

I'm trying to implement the project in the Android site's "Managing the Activity Lifecycle" training exercise at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html .

The instructions don't say how to set it up.  A *.zip file is provided, but I can't figure out how to get it to work.  No matter what I do, there are errors that keep the project from running.

What is the proper procedure for getting this project to work?

Answer (score 4):

Before open managing lifecycle project, check for updates in eclipse Help drop down. Then follow these steps which i have done to open project and run successfully:

- Point your cursor on file drop down -> then, tap on import
- A dialog box open, point your cursor on Android, and then select **Existing Android code into workspace** as shown in image below:

  [image: import android project]
- After choose android code option, select project root source directory shown in figure below:

  [image: choose project source]

Since i am already import the project so it shows **Select at least one project prompt**

- Next, point your cursor on finish button. All is done, eclipse import our managing project shows in project explorer window on left pane.

Run your project either through device or in emulator, its an awesome activity lifecycle example demo by google. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would have already completed the tutorial [Building Your First App](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html).

If so then you simply need to extract the zip file and then in eclipse select File>Import and then select Android and follow on the wizard from there. It should compile just fine.

Comment: Could you go into more detail?  Should there be an activity-lifecycle folder in my workspace initially?  When I select File->Import, where do I go from here?

Comment: Yes, I have not only completed the Building Your First App tutorial but also published an app on Google Play.  (It's a fun little app called Upgrade Your Cereal.)

Comment: Here's the steps you need to follow in order to get this working:
1. Extract it into your downloads folder
2. Open eclipse. Select File>Import
3. Android>Existing code into workspace
4. Select the Browse button next to "Root Directory:" and pick the "activity-lifecycle" directory and press OK.
5. click finish and let eclipse do any processing required (Loading android sdk, etc.)
6. Try running it in an emulator or device.

Comment: (Using Eclipse 3.6.2) I've followed steps 1, 2 and 3 but the Eclipse Import dialog says "No projects are found to import". (Note: there is no "Existing code into workspace" option: the option I've selected is "Existing projects into workspace") (Also note that I extracted the contents of the downloaded zip file into my C:\Users\[MyName]\Eclipse folder rather than my Downloads folder. Would that make a difference?) (Also note: like jhsu802701 I've also had some experience with Android coding and have successfully loaded previous demos like Notepad into Eclipse, but I'm stumped by this one!)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well while working through the tutorials.  I was trying to import the 'activityLifecycle' project into eclipse and nothing would happen, tried several different methods.

It turns out that there has been a toolkit update recently (probably coinciding with the new version release).  Update your Eclipse with 'Check for Updates' in the Help menu then install.  Install other packages using the android SDK Manager (click on the android with the down arrow in eclipse) then install the recommended packages (you will need to be administrator to do this).

After Eclipse and android has been updated you should be able to import the package using the import command and the unzipped project folder.  It did pop up a few warnings but the project still runs fine in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. From Eclipse, Do a File->Import, Choose "Existing android code into workspace" and select the extracted 'activity-lifecycle' directory. Make sure you didn't extract the 'activity-lifecycle' zip in your workspace and is outside at some other location.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Android Studio, this the way that this example works for me

1.- Open project -> Import project files (Eclipse ADT, Gradle etc) 
2.- Select your folder, I selected activity-lifecycle and click ok

it takes some times to convert the project at the end it will fail to compile due the sdk, so
1.- close the project
2.- explores de files of the project on look for this file build.gradle
3.- open this file to change this values  compileSdkVersion,  buildToolsVersion, minSdkVersion, and  targetSdkVersion. Use the value of a previous project that had compiled sucessfully and save the changes
4.-open this project and it will work. that's it.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who had difficulties with the explanations here, these are the steps that worked for me, in some detail:

1. Download ActivityLifecycle.zip, and unzip to a directory of your choice.
2. Start Android Studio and select 'Import Project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc')
   A window will appear: 'Select Eclipse or Gradle Project to Import'. Use this to navigate to the folder you unzipped in the previous steps and select that folder. Finally, click Ok.
3. When you clicked 'Ok' in the previous step, a new window appears: 'Import Project from ADT (Eclipse Android). Click next to use the automatically generated import destination directory. On the next page, leave all items checked and click 'Finish.'
4. If you are using a proxy, the Proxy Settings window will appear next. In that case, set your host and port number accordingly.
5. At this point the project will open in Android Studio but with a warning dialog: 
   Frameworks detected
   Android framework is detected in the project Configure.
6. Click Configure in the warning dialog and a new window will appear: 'Setup Frameworks'.
7. Click ok in the new 'Setup Frameworks' window.
8. Expand the Gradle Scripts item in the Project sidebar.
9. Double-click the build.gradle(Module:app) item; this will open the app level gradle build file for the imported application. When you install Android Studio, you typically install some subset of the available SDK's. The build.gradle file for the imported project may not compile against any of SDKs you have in your Android Studio setup so you have to edit this file to match. In my case, I am writing code to compile against SDK version 17; this is also my target platform. So, I use this information to edit the build.gradle file for the imported project.

Here is how the code looks before the change:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 14
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.lifecycle"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 15
        ...
```

And here is how it looks after:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.lifecycle"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 17
        ...
```

At this point, the import process should be complete and the Eclipse project is now 'converted' into a project that respects Android Studio conventions. I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

For those of you who had difficulties with this solution, I have elaborated the steps in some detail:

1. Download ActivityLifecycle.zip, and unzip to a directory of your choice.
2. Start Android Studio and select 'Import Project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc')
   A window will appear: 'Select Eclipse or Gradle Project to Import'. Use this to navigate to the folder you unzipped in the previous steps and select that folder. Finally, click Ok.
3. When you clicked 'Ok' in the previous step, a new window appears: 'Import Project from ADT (Eclipse Android). Click next to use the automatically generated import destination directory. On the next page, leave all items checked and click 'Finish.'
4. If you are using a proxy, the Proxy Settings window will appear next. In that case, set your host and port number accordingly.
5. At this point the project will open in Android Studio but with a warning dialog: 
   Frameworks detected
   Android framework is detected in the project Configure.
6. Click Configure in the warning dialog and a new window will appear: 'Setup Frameworks'.
7. Click ok in the new 'Setup Frameworks' window.
8. Expand the Gradle Scripts item in the Project sidebar.
9. Double-click the build.gradle(Module:app) item; this will open the app level gradle build file for the imported application. When you install Android Studio, you typically install some subset of the available SDK's. The build.gradle file for the imported project may not compile against any of SDKs you have in your Android Studio setup so you have to edit this file to match. In my case, I am writing code to compile against SDK version 17; this is also my target platform. So, I use this information to edit the build.gradle file for the imported project.

Here is how the code looks before the change:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 14
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.lifecycle"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 15
        ...
```

And here is how it looks after:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.lifecycle"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 17
        ...
```

At this point, the import process should be complete and the Eclipse project is now 'converted' into a project that respects Android Studio conventions. I hope this helps!

Comment: Please include all information required to make this answer complete - we can't rely on links to arbitrary sites

Comment: Based on the pending edit suggestion, it looks like you accidentally created two accounts. You can [contact the team](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) to have them merged, which will allow you to regain direct editing privileges on your contributions.